# Merging pandas dataframes duplicates some data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

I'm using Python pandas and merging information from a number of CSV and TSV files. When I execute the 2nd merge data is duplicated in the resulting dataframe. I'm assuming, I'm missing something basic with the merge call but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Code:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd 
import sys
import matplotlib

# Enable inline plotting
%matplotlib inline

# read data into dataframes
ticketdata = r'/pathto.csv'
ticketdata = r'/pathto.csv'
userdata = r'/pathto.csv'
shipmentdata = r'/pathto.tsv'

tickets_df = pd.read_csv((ticketdata), usecols=['Id',"Requester",'Created at',"Requester email",
                                                "Requester external id"])
users_df = pd.read_csv((userdata), usecols=['External ID','Printers',"Organization Title"])
shipment_df = pd.read_csv((shipmentdata), delimiter='\t', usecols=['Cust','Printer ID'])

# Clean up tickets_df & shipment_df

# Change "Requester external id" to "External ID" to support the merge
tickets_df.columns = ['Ticket Id',"Requester","External ID","Requester email",'Created at']
shipment_df.columns = ['VAR','Printers']
# Change column order for the sake of readability
tickets_df = tickets_df[['Ticket Id','Requester','Created at',"Requester email","External ID"]]

# Replace NaN in External ID with 0 and merge data
tickets_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
merge1_df = pd.merge(tickets_df, users_df, on=['External ID'], how='left')
merge1_df = merge1_df[['Ticket Id','Created at',"Organization Title",'Requester',"Requester email","External ID",'Printers']]
merge2_df = pd.merge(merge1_df, shipment_df, on=['Printers'], how='left')
```

merge1_df looks as expected (NaN is expected for some values):

```
    Ticket Id   Created at  Organization Title  Requester   Requester email     External ID     Printers
0   1   2014-08-21 18:19    NaN     dude    dude@dude.com   0   NaN
1   2   2014-09-09 12:04    NaN     dude1   duke1@dude.com  0   NaN
2   3   2014-09-09 12:04    NaN     dude2   duke2@dude.com  0   NaN
3   4   2014-09-09 12:04    NaN     dude3   duke3@dude.com  0   NaN
```

merge2_df contains thousands of dupes:

```
    Ticket Id   Created at  Organization Title  Requester   Requester email     External ID     Printers
0   1   2014-08-21 18:19    NaN     dude    dude@dude.com   0   NaN
1   1   2014-08-21 18:19    NaN     dude    dude@dude.com   0   NaN
2   1   2014-08-21 18:19    NaN     dude    dude@dude.com   0   NaN
3   1   2014-08-21 18:19    NaN     dude    dude@dude.com   0   NaN
```

Any idea(s) how I am messing up merge2_df?

Comment: This is too much code to attempt to read through and we don't have access to your CSVs.  But presumably if you have duplicates post-merge, you had duplicate keys pre-merge.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with NaN values in the shipment_df dataframe. I added the following to replace NaN with 0  and the duplicate entries in merge2_df were resolved

```
shipment_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```